# how to sort nested dictionaries based on multiple keys

Tags: python-3.x

I need to sort the dictionary `dicti` and display  as follows:
compile the following statistics for each player:

1. Number of best-of-5 set matches won
2. Number of best-of-3 set matches won
3. Number of sets won
4. Number of games won
5. Number of sets lost
6. Number of games lost
   You should print out to the screen (standard output) a summary in decreasing order of ranking, where the ranking is according to the criteria 1-6 in that order (compare item 1, if equal compare item 2, if equal compare item 3 etc, noting that for items 5 and 6 the comparison is reversed).

I have stored the results in dictionary but I am not familiar with sorting of dictionaries. I've no clue how to do it.

```
dicti={'Federer': {'gameswon': 142, 'gameslost': 143, 'setswon': 13, 'setslost': 16, 'fivesetmatch': 3, 'threesetmatch': 1}, 

'Nadal': {'gameswon': 143, 'gameslost': 142, 'setswon': 16, 'setslost': 13, 'fivesetmatch': 2, 'threesetmatch': 2}, 

'Halep': {'gameswon': 15, 'gameslost': 12, 'setswon': 2, 'setslost': 1, 'fivesetmatch': 0, 'threesetmatch': 1},

'Wozniacki': {'gameswon': 12, 'gameslost': 15, 'setswon': 1, 'setslost': 2, 'fivesetmatch': 0, 'threesetmatch': 0}}
```

Comment: Sorting needs something to sort by, do you want to sort the dict by "key" (i.e. player name in this case)? Or do you want to sort by something else like the number of games won?

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas for data analysis and getting insights

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicti)
>>> df
               Federer  Nadal  Halep  Wozniacki
gameswon           142    143     15         12
gameslost          143    142     12         15
setswon             13     16      2          1
setslost            16     13      1          2
fivesetmatch         3      2      0          0
threesetmatch        1      2      1          0
>>> df.describe()
          Federer       Nadal      Halep  Wozniacki
count    6.000000    6.000000   6.000000    6.00000
mean    53.000000   53.000000   5.166667    5.00000
std     69.561484   69.558608   6.554896    6.69328
min      1.000000    2.000000   0.000000    0.00000
25%      5.500000    4.750000   1.000000    0.25000
50%     14.500000   14.500000   1.500000    1.50000
75%    110.500000  110.500000   9.500000    9.50000
max    143.000000  143.000000  15.000000   15.00000
```

For example,

For number of games won you could do

```
>>> df.loc['gameswon'].sum()
312
```